# How to configure flexible access rules

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, polish-notation

**BASIC PROBLEM TO SOLVE**

I am trying to configure flexible rules using user groups and ir.rules in Odoo 10. Basically I want to give users access only to certain records, based on specific values in columns. There are some records that I want to restrict - regardless if it was allowed in another group based on different criteria.

**Here are some simplified examples of what I want to accomplish:**

1.

```
(country = 'USA'
or
office= London)

and

vip = false
```

2.

```
(country = 'uk'
or
country = 'netherlands'
or
office = London)

etc
```

To make the access rules flexible, I want to create the following groups:

- group_country_usa
- group_country_germany
- group_country_uk
- group_country_netherlands

etc

- group_office_london
- group_office_new_york
- group_office_paris
- group_office_tokyo
- group_office_st_petersburg

etc

- group_no_vips

I have corresponding ir.rules records for each group above:

```
[('country','=', 'usa')]
etc

[('office','=', 'amsterdam')]
etc

[('vip','=', False)]
```

Per my testing I do not believe I can do the the above with only using separate ir.rules records.

Is there a way I can accomplish my objective?

I hope the above makes sense and that someone can hint me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's a global rule allowing access to all records, I see no problem with using your described `ir.rule` and `res.groups` configuration. However, group rules are additive, meaning it is not possible to join `ir.rule` domains with `and` like in your example #1. See official [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That makes sense. Would there be any other/better way I could accomplish my goal?

Comment: Without additional python development you can not achieve something you described. How we usually implement such a functionality is we define `allowed_countries`, `allowed_offices`, etc. fields on a partner. Then `ir.rule` is defined on your record with domain like this `[('country', 'in', partner_id.allowed_countries)]` etc. But as I said, it requires extra development.